# How put data in app.blade.php from controller in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, controller

I Need to put some dynamic data from controller to app.blade.php, but I can't find any controller. Where I sholud do this?
Thanks

Comment: Read these two seconds in the Laravel documentation: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views

Comment: I mean controller which load app.blade.php. because I need put some data into header.

Comment: It isn't loaded by any controller. It's extended by the views you render. You can pass data there or better, use a [view composer](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views#view-composers)

Comment: Could you show me How I should to this? I need add function which will be returned variable.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To inject data into a layout view (a view that's `@extend`ed by others) you can use a view composer. How you do that is actually pretty well [explained in the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views#view-composers)

Create a service provider (inside `app/Providers`):

```
<?php namespace App\Providers;

use View;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }


    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Now inside the `boot()` method you register your view composer:

```
View::composer('app', function($view){
    $view->with('foo', 'bar');
});
```

After that, don't forget to register the service provider in `config/app.php` by adding it to the `providers` array:

```
'providers' => [
    // other providers
    'App\Providers\ComposerServiceProvider'
]
```

Comment: why this dosent work for me? i am usin laravel 5.6 and i added `ComposerServiceProvider` and it is giving me `no such variable foo` when i am trying to open the view. do i need to refresh the settings or something?

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to lukasgeiter's answer. But it needs some modifications to get it working with all the views rendered by Laravel.

You need to put '*' character as a wildcard, so you may attach a composer to all views

```
View::composer('*', function($view){
    //any code to set $val variable
    $val = 'bar';
    $view->with('foo', $val);
});
```

so complete class of `app\Providers\ComposerServiceProvider.php` will be like,

```
<?php 
namespace App\Providers;
use View;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function boot()
    {
        View::composer('*', function($view){
            //any code to set $val variable
            $val = 'bar';
            $view->with('foo', $val);
        });
    }

    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Also register service provider in `config\app.php` file as,

```
'providers' => [
    // Other Service Providers...
    App\Providers\ComposerServiceProvider::class,
],
```

Now you can use `$foo` variable in your `resources\views\layouts\app.blade.php` file as

```
<div>
   {{$foo}}
</div>
```

this will render to client as

```
<div>
   bar
</div>
```